# MariaDB slave replication server from many sources?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

can I have one server, which is slave for like 500 masters? All the masters have different content, but they inserting is like once per minute, so I think 8 core slave should be sufficient for it.
And also can I have one master database on this slave server? I don't have to, but it would reduce our servers costs.
Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about "500", but there is "multi-source" replication in *recent* versions of MySQL, plus MariaDB.

So that is 500 inserts per minute on the Slave?  8/second is no problem.  Even 1 core would not be taxed.  Even if all inserts went into the same table.

Even if multi-source did not let you have 500, you could put, say, 25 instances of MySQL on a single server, each receiving data from 20 Masters.